# Show tooltip over all <td>s in a row but the last one

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

The only valid solution I can think of is adding the tooltip to each `<td>` (there are about ten per line, so the first 9), but I was wondering if there is any way to add the tooltip to the `<tr>` and then exclude the last `<td>` of displaying it.

My colleagues used Bootstrap for the styles (I haven't used it yet, but maybe it is relevant to the question).

Comment: Is tr > td:last:hover what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set title only on [tr] and use a simple script to prevent tooltip on last-child

```
var ttip;

$(' tr > td:last-child').mouseenter(function() {
    ttip = $(this).parent().attr('title');
  $(this).parent().attr('title','');
});

$(' tr > td:last-child').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).parent().attr('title',ttip);
});
```

Trivially you detect mouseenter on last [td] to remove the title of its [tr] (saving its value), and on mouseleave of last-child you restore saved title.

[Here a working jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/berets/wk56ebgk/)